# UIAutoresizingMasks works wrong in iPad ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autoresizingmask, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a container view `ECSlidingViewController`. Every item in the container is a `NavigationViewController`  -->  `UIViewController`

For example in one child view controller I have a `UITableView` with a `UICollectionView` in one static cell.

I try to implement a version for iPad that supports changing orientation of the screen, so I enabled all the authoresizing masks to fill the cell with the `UICollectionView` - and now I had a crazy issue - the frame of the cells - their width is very big. For example the table view frame is `{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}` but the `UICollectionView` in static cell frame is `{{0, 0}, {1792, 1301}}`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm invalidating collectionView layout in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` so `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is called again.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView..frame.size.height);
}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Suppress the layout errors by invalidating the layout
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];    
}
```

Comment: valenki, borsch, zemlyanika. The problem is not connected with the collection view - everything in the cells not working correctly with a autoresizing masks because of strange frame sizes

Comment: hm... the code should fix the sizes of collection view cells, on rotation.

Comment: now the collection view items are one under another ==> the result is one very looong collection view with only one element per row

Comment: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/211 they had already this kind of issue, maybe that will help with something